# What is this yellow powder on my exhaust manifold?

Tags: exhaust, exhaust-manifold

I took off the heat shield from the exhaust manifold on my 2003 Nissan Primera while looking for an exhaust leak, and I noticed this yellowish poweder / dust on it:

[image]

Any ideas what it is?

**EDIT Sept. 19th 2017**

So I wiped a section of the yellow powder with my finger and this was the result:

[image]

There seems to be another layer of something under the powder which got wiped away at the same time, and the yellow powder itself seems grainy.

I also verified ( as well as I could ) that there is only one exhaust leak which is from the base of the O2 sensor.  I [stuck a funnel in a length of hose](http://www.instructables.com/id/Find-an-exhaust-leak-without-burning-your-hands/) and had my wife block the exhaust with a rag and this was the only place I heard anything, and the change in sound was quite pronounced when she blocked the exhaust.

Comment: How does the heat shield looks like on the inside?

Comment: What is the heat shield and manifold made out of (what metal - if you can tell)?

Comment: No one has asked this:  Is it loose dust that you can wipe with your finger?  Is there a layer of "stuff" embedded on the surface and then also loose dust?  It looks like there is sharp line of difference in the top left of the photo, leading away from the sensor.  What's on the other side?  Which way is gravity pulling?  It looks much thicker on the "top" (of the photo).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I can't tell what it's made out of.  Maybe stainless steels as it has no signs of corrosion of any kind on it.

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski I vaguely remember I could brush some off when I accidental rubbed up against it.  Not sure about the embedded part. In this picture right is up and left is down.  The O2 is just above the 3-way cat which is connected directly to the exhaust manifold.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes Is this a gasoline or diesel engine?  Interesting question by the way.

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski It's a gasoline engine.

Comment: Could it be possible that the previous owner used fuel that he bought from another country that has some "relaxed" regulations regarding sulfur content in fuel?

Comment: @Myself I think it's highly unlikely. I updated the question.

Comment: I have a hunch that it's a chromium compound because there are several that form yellow powder or crystals in the exhaust's temperature range.  Chromium is used in (stainless) steel exhaust pipes. Can you scrape some of it off and put it into a cup of water to see how well it dissolves (solubility)? You're in Israel right? In North America, we use NaCl on our roads for ice; I assume you don't. Are there any chemicals that vehicles would be exposed to there? ([Reference, pages ~41, ~62](https://books.google.com/books?id=DVdCqL9NbOcC&printsec=frontcover))

Comment: The most likely culprit is just dust that got burned on (as Myself said).  Is there dust on any other component? Does that component get (very) hot? Is it present on your calipers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IMHO that powder is either:

- Dust, that got "burned" by the hot exhaust manifold and transformed into some yellow-looking substance.
- Sulfur, as the color has a striking resemblance to sulfur. The presence of sulfur could indicate a leak and a faulty emission treatment system. There are [test strips](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DBH4DQ) available to test for sulfur. Should you decide to try a test please get informed about the correct procedure and the risks of this test (lead acetate and Hydrogen sulfide are poisonous)

Comment: I apparently have an exhaust leak somewhere in that area although I haven't located it yet.

Comment: When I sprayed soapy water on the O2 sensor connection I got bubbling, so I assume I've got a leak there.  I also got some bubbles in the area right about the sensor where the four pipes join together; there's allot of yellow powder in both areas.  Makes me think you're right and this is sulfur from an exhaust leak.

Comment: How are you pressurizing the exhaust system?  If the car is running are you sure the bubbles are air leaks and not boiling?

Comment: That's a lot of sulphur, if that's what it is.  Most countries now have 50ppm or less in petrol and [diesel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-low-sulfur_diesel).  Also I wouldn't expect it to be deposited as elemental sulphur, which burns well if unpleasantly.  The deposition also doesn't look like it's from a single point leak.

Comment: @ChrisH I agree, that's what is making me wonder about the whole issue

Comment: I (used to) have a completely different way of testing for sulphur, but that relies on access to hundreds of thousands of £/$/€ of lab equipment meant for something else!

Comment: @self.name I considered that possibility also.  I started with a completely cold engine, sprayed before I started the engine, and noticed when I sprayed other areas the soapy water evaporated as opposed to bubbled.

Comment: @ChrisH I only bought this car recently and I suspect the leaks have been there a very long time.  Also, I suspect there is an additional leak above the O2 where the four pipes converge; I also saw bubbling when I sprayed in that area.

Comment: I highly doubt it is pure, elemental sulphur. @RobertS.Barnes Can you scrape some off and attempt to burn it? YouTube has several videos showing what it should look like. Sulphur melts at 240F (115C) and boils at 832F (445C); your exhaust starts ~around/above 832F in the manifolds and gets even hotter around the cat. Once exhaust exits through a leak, it would be quickly blown away. The sulphur in vehicle exhaust is *primarily* sulphur dioxide which **can't be a liquid or solid outside of a freezer**. Also, the fact that there is very little sulphur in today's fuel.

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski I updated the question.

Answer (score 12):

If your engine was running / exhaust manifold hot; the yellow is then zinc oxide. It would result from a galvanized steel manifold which has naturally oxidized. At room temperature the ZnO is white , I forget the temperature where it turns yellow.

Comment: the manifold was completely cold when I took this picture.  it had been at least 6 hours since the engine ran.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes - blacksmith37 is actually stating if the exhaust gets too hot while running it may turn yellow, not at the time the picture was taken.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Robert is correct.

This yellow powder is Hexavalent Chromium CR(VI), the most toxic form of chromium.  It is found on exhaust manifolds as a result of heating stainless steel to 600°C.  Do not get it on your skin or inhale it.

Here are additional references:

- https://www.osha.gov/sites/default/files/publications/OSHA-3373-hexavalent-chromium.pdf
- https://www.mammothequipment.ca/safety-bulletin-hexavalent-chromium-cr-vi

Regarding the other answers here:

- Zinc Oxide becomes yellow only when heated.  It returns to powder white when cool.
- Any dust would be burned off on the exhaust
- Sulfur is also yellow, but would have burned off the exhaust as well

This is not dust, ZnO or S.  The yellow powder is Cr-6.

## Decontamination

According to a [Technical Information Bulletin from Caterpillar](https://www.eneria.fr/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Bulletin-Information-Technique-Caterpillar-chrome-6-VO.pdf) and a [2004 Article](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15488923/):

> In the event that hexavalent chromium is discovered, Caterpillar recommends following all local guidelines
> and wearing the correct PPE during the decontamination and removal process.
> There are multiple methods of cleaning material that can be considered. Once such method is to utilize a
> solution consisting of 10% citric acid, 10% ascorbic acid and 80% distilled water to convert the hexavalent
> chromium powder to a trivalent chromium state.
> Special care should be taken to prevent agitating the powder and creating airborne dust.[1](https://www.eneria.fr/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Bulletin-Information-Technique-Caterpillar-chrome-6-VO.pdf)

(Ascorbic acid is vitamin C.)

> The results indicate that vitamin C could be used in effective remediation of Cr(VI)-contaminated soils and groundwater in a wide range of pH, with or without sunlight.[2](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15488923/)

Answer (score 0):

Be wary, this could be hexavalent chromium, which is extremely toxic and a new hazard that has been recently identified with stainless steel and high temperatures, particularly in the presence of calcium-containing insulation.

https://www.eneria.fr/en/hexavalent-chromium-or-chromium-6-cr-6-on-engines/